# Android Button performClick

Tags: android, button, multi-touch

In order to fudge multitouch buttons, I set a massive invisible imageView over top of everything. The I just poll for where it was touched and call performClick on the button in that area under it. Now my problem is that performClick only calls the onClick method, and doesn't actually perform a legitimate button press, so there's no animation (color change etc). I have a custom xml for the buttons, and it worked fine without the imageView. I try using setPressed and setEnabled, but the png never changes, and the button looks static. What am I missing?

Comment: What precisely are you trying to do with such a complicated design?  There may be a better approach that you are missing, I expect.

Comment: @James Black Like I said, I'm trying to multitouch buttons, and there really is no simpler way that I could find ( after hours of research). Whenever you touch any single view, that view basically hijacks all the touch events until it's done doing whatever, meaning if you press one button, you can't press any others, hence the massive imageView on top--it's a single view, so I have it handle all the touch.

Comment: @wehweh, instead of using a Button, why don't you use a View, which does support multi-touch?

Comment: @Phil Because I need buttons. My question here isn't how to do multitouch, it's how to change the drawable state on the buttons.

Comment: @wehweh, in that case you should be able to override the method `onTouchEvent(...)`. From the `MotionEvent`, which is passed in, you can find the pointer id, which Android uses to keep track of which finger is pressed down first, second, etc.

Comment: @Phil Again, my issue is not multitouch. Did you really read the original post? I call setEnabled and setPressed on a Button object and the drawable doesn't change. What method calls am I missing for the button's state to change? That's all.

Comment: @wehweh, I was merely going off of James Black's query about whether or not you were using the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

How about tying a Boolean to each button. All the button logic does is flip flop the variable and maybe change an indicator (button color or text) to pushed/not pushed. Shouldn't be more than 3 or 4 lines of code executed per button press. Fire the heavy code when a 'do it' button is pressed. That would have to be faster than computing which button was pressed under the overlay...